# Matrix manipulation?

Tags: java

I am having a problem creating a matrix program in Java where I have to do the following:

```
          1   2   3  6
          4   5   6  15
          7   8   9  24
       15 12  15  18 15
```

Above is a matrix, and the sum is printed of each row, column and diagonal at their respective ends.  I have to make this logic in a method and then return the value to main defined in other class i.e

```
class A
{
    public static int[][](int a[][])
    {
        //logic
    }
}
class B
{
    public static void main(String... s)
    {
        //call
    }
}
```

......

I have made this far ..

```
class MatrixAdd
{
    public static int[][] matrixAdd(int x[][])
    {
        int i,j;
        int y[][]=new int[4][5];
        for( i=0;i<y.length-1;i++)
        {
            for( j=0;j<y[i].length-2;j++)
            {
                y[i][j+1]=x[i][j];
            }
        }
        for( i=0;i<x.length;i++)
        {
            int sum=0;
            for( j=0;j<x[i].length;j++)
            {
                sum=sum+x[i][j];
            }
            y[i][j+1]=sum;
            //System.out.println(sum);
        }
        for( i=0;i<x.length;i++)
        {
            int sum=0;
            for( j=0;j<x[i].length;j++)
            {
                sum=sum+x[j][i];
            }
            y[j+1][i+1]=sum;
            //System.out.println(sum);
        }
        return y;
    }
}
class MatrixAddRun
{
    public static void main(String... s)
    {
        int a[][]=new int[4][5];
        a=MatrixAdd.matrixAdd(new int[][]{
                                                        {1,2,3},
                                                        {4,5,6},
                                                        {7,8,9}});
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<a[i].length;j++)
            {
                System.out.print("\t"+a[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this homework?  It really looks like it... and you haven't tried anything.  You expect us to fill in the blanks for you.  Also, how did you want these sums printed?  Should the rows come first? The columns come first? The diagonals?  Here's a hint to get you started.  Think `for` loops and keep one row or column constant while iterating through the other dimension.  For the diagonals, both rows and columns are going to change.

Comment: Sounds like you are having trouble with your homework!

Comment: Actually i am not having problem calculating the sums of rows , columns and diagonals instead i am having problem representing like this.since i can only return the matrix from the method , so i have to do all the manipulations within this method only.

Comment: Create a new matrix that has 2 additional rows and columns, copy the matrix in the middle, the compute the respective sums along the borders as per your example.  Leave the first column (except for the last row) as 0.

Comment: I am really sorry,i am just a beginner so please forgive,actually i am having problem in copying the matrix in middle.Can you please illustrate.

Answer (score 1):

> Actually i am having problem in copying the matrix in middle.  Can you please illustrate.

Sorry, no.

<sup>That would defeat the purpose of your homework ... which is to gain a deeper understanding of Java arrays and indexing by *doing all of the work yourself*.  And if you don't agree, then I'm sure your textbooks and/or lecture notes have examples that will help.</sup>

But here are some hints.

1. Assuming that the input array is rectangular, you need to create a new array with the same dimensions and size as the input array; e.g. `new int[x][y]` for appropriate values of `x` and `y`.
2. You will need to use nested loops to copy the array elements.
3. A 2D array in Java is really an array of 1D arrays, and so on.
4. The size of a 1D array `a` is `a.length` and the elements are indexed from zero to `a.length - 1`.

Comment: Thanks for not telling me,I managed to copy the matrix in middle.

Answer (score -1):

If all you need is to show the matrix, is as simple as this:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    int[][] matrix = {
        {1,2,3},
        {4,5,6},
        {7,8,9}
    }

    int[][] results = yourfunction(matrix);
    for(int i=0;i<results.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<results[i].length;j++){
            System.out.print(results[i][j]+"    ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP would also like the row, column and diagonal sums displayed in addition to the matrix.  Also, this new matrix has to be created in another class, and has to be returned in a method in that class.  This is just printing out the original matrix contents itself.